# How do I prove that if the divergence of a field is 0, then it's a curl of another field?

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator, curl

The title says it all,
Thank you very much in advance, having an exam tommorow :)

Comment: This is a straight corollary of Helmholtz decomposition theorem (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition)

Comment: And it only holds for sufficiently smooth vector fields. They need to have partial differentiability twice, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to provide a fuller statement of the problem you want help with.  The title may give Readers a good idea of what the problem is about, but relying on it alone to give the problem statement often leads (as here) to overlooking or omitting important details.

Comment: You should not have mentioned the exam. Ask for the proper keyword instead (the death squad wouldn't even give you that). The keyword is **Poincaré Lemma**. Note that the claim is only true "locally", e.g., in balls.